# Ranking in python

Tags: python, python-3.6, ranking, rank

Good day guys, I am struggling to write a function   to rank numbers. The code is working but two things ain't working well. We know if two numbers are the same, they get the same position (or rank)  but from my code,  the two same numbers have different rankings. Also when it gets to 21st,  the code prints 21th in instead of 21st. How can I solve this issue.  This the code

```
a = [20,50,67,100,93,89,72,81,79,66,49,73,29,50,52,69,71,70,71,84,67]

 def ranker(zed):
      prefixes = ["st", "nd", "rd" ,"th"]
      zed.sort(reverse =True) 
      found = [ ]

     for dig in zed:
          pre =  len(found) + 1
          if len(found) > 3:
                found.append(str(dig) + " " + str(pre) + prefixes[ 3 ])
     else:
           found.append(str(dig) + " " + str(pre) + prefixes[ len(found) ])
           print(found) 
           ranker(a)
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that, while we always encourage everyone to properly format their code, it is critical for Python because of the whitespace-based syntax. Thus, make sure your code is well-formatted, then indent it four extra spaces to mark it as code for Stack Overflow (you can do it automatically by selecting your code and hitting Ctrl-K or Cmd-K).

Comment: more suited as a code review question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you want.

```
a = [20,50,67,100,93,89,72,81,79,66,49,73,29,50,52,69,71,70,71,84,67]
def ranker(zed):
    prefixes = ["st", "nd", "rd" ,"th"]
    zed.sort(reverse =True)
    found = [ ]
    for dig in zed:
        pre = len(found) + 1
        if found and dig==int(found[-1].split(' ')[0]):
            found.append(found[-1])
        else:
            if pre > 3:
                if pre>20 and pre%10<3 and pre%100<10 or pre%100>20:
                    found.append(str(dig) + " " + str(pre) + prefixes[len(found)%10])
                else:
                    found.append(str(dig) + " " + str(pre) + prefixes[ 3 ])
            else:
                found.append(str(dig) + " " + str(pre) + prefixes[len(found)])
    print(found)
ranker(a)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The code prints the first 4 numbers and their positions. The earlier code you posted worked fine just that the duplicate numbers have different rankings

Comment: Marcus, thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it

Comment: Marcus, I tried to increase the list(a) by adding more values to it but I got IndexError: list index out of range. How can I solve that

Comment: You can increase list(a) with + operator or append function. Example: a=[1,2], a+=[3]. A then become [1,2,3]. a.append(3) will also make a [1,2,3]. Check the link here, https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/06/python-list/?utm_source=feedly

Answer (score 1):

Something simpler

First we find duplicate entries and we store number of occurrences of each duplicate entry, so we can use later to append necessary entry multiple times.

To handle correct prefixes, we created a list of first 20 elements. We reuse first 10 if position > 20.

Note : finding duplicates is not really efficient in my code. We could use **Counter** here instead ( perhaps this would be nicer approach )

```
a =[20,50,67,100,93,89,72,81,79,66,49,73,29,50,52,69,71,70,71,84,67]

def ranker(zed):
    #prefixes = ["st", "nd", "rd",  * ["th"] * 17]
    prefixes = ["st", "nd", "rd"] +  [ "th"  for _ in range(17) ]
    duplicates = {x : zed.count(x) for x in zed if zed.count(x) > 1}
    zedset = sorted(set(zed))    

    found = [ ]

    for count, dig in enumerate(reversed(zedset),1):
        z = 20 if count % 100 <= 20 else 10 
        occurs = duplicates.get(dig , 1)

        for _ in range(occurs):
            found.append(str(dig) + " " + str(count) + prefixes[(count - 1) % z])
        print(found)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to have the  duplicate numbers with the same position or ranking

Comment: @billstone09 updated to deal with duplicate. would this work for you ?

Comment: Martin, I'm getting error on line 3. SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target

Comment: Your python version ? i guess it is 2.7. Updated the answer to deal with the problem on line 3